# Recursion and substrings in Java

Tags: java, string, recursion, substring

How would you create a recursive method

```
getSubstrings("abc")
```

which returns a list of all the possible substrings of that string e.g.

```
{ "a", "b", "c", "ab", "bc", "ac", "abc" }
```

Comment: "ac" is not a substring of "abc". And "" is a substring of "abc".

Comment: not clear if order is important: should be also bac cab cba acb bca or  not?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say that [_this here link_](http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2014/02/algorithm-for-combinations-of-string-java-code-with-example.html) will likely help. I found it by googling: `find all ordered combinations of characters in string java`

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to write down a clear and verifiable spec for the function, and possibly avoid giving example output which contradicts that spec. Without that first step, you obviously can't proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I see that what you want is combinations and not substrings. Following is code for all combinations.

Recursively it starts with first character and adds to list ie `a`, then recursively calls next character and adds to list `ab` and then next `abc` and now no more character so it backtracks and instead of adding `b` it now adds `c` so adds `ac` and then same procedure repeats with next character `b`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.out.println(combination("abc"));
    }
    public static List<String> combination(String str) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        combination("", str, list); 
        return list;
    }
    public static void combination(String sub, String str, List<String> list) {
        if (sub.length() != 0) list.add(sub);
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            combination(sub + str.charAt(i), str.substring(i + 1), list);
        }
    }  
}
```

output : `[a, ab, abc, ac, b, bc, c]`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use recursive algorithm (like the one provided by @sujithvm), you can use this iterative algorithm:

```
String str = "abc";
for (int i = 1; i < (1 << str.length()); i++) {
  String comb = "";
  for (int j = 0, k = 1; k <= i; j++, k <<= 1) {
    if (i & k == 1) {
      comb += str.charAt(j);
    }
  }
  System.out.println(comb);
}
```

This method first generates all possible combinations of `str`. These combinations are represented as a sequence of binary digits, where digit 0 (respectively, 1) at position X means that the character in `str` at position X is not included (respectively,included). For example, for `str = "abc"`, the combinations are 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, and 111. 110 indicates that the charater *a* and *b* are included, while character *c* is not. So, 110 represents the combination *ab*.